# How to disable git pull.rebase (rebasing by default upon pull)

Tags: git

I tried setting

```
git config --global pull.rebase false
```

and

```
git config pull.rebase false
```

and when I run

```
git config --global pull.rebase
```

or

```
git config pull.rebase
```

I see false, but when I run `git pull ...` it still is doing a rebase. How can I make this go away again?

Comment: There is also this `branch.<name>.rebase`, being `<name>` the name of the branch you are pulling...

Comment: Your command `git config --global pull.rebase false` solved it for me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### The *best* way

Don't use `git pull`.  Just run `git fetch` and then when it's done, run `git merge`.

(This is also the best way to do rebase pulls: don't use `git pull`.  ["This ... is wrong tool.  Never use this."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v79fYnuVzdI))

#### The other way

Use `git pull --rebase=false`.  The command line flag overrides the configuration setting.

Comment: Credit for the B5 link. But if it's '_wrong_' why does it exist?

Comment: @geotheory: Some people like it, and think it's convenient. It predates the invention of the *upstream* setting, and back then—in 2006 or so—it was generally the way to do things.

Comment: Confusing, as I understood upstream setting links a local branch to a remote branch so that simpler calls like `git pull` become unambiguous and so are enabled.

Comment: @geotheory: Not exactly. The upstream of a branch is a pair of names: a remote name (or `.` to mean "self"), and a branch name as found on the Git specified by that remote name. That information then gets used *by* `git pull`. Before remotes existed, you always had to specify everything: `git pull <url> <branch>`; the invention of remotes allowed shortening this to `git pull`, but it also allows running `git fetch` followed by a second Git command, without having to type in the `<url>` and `<branch>` parts. So it used to be more convenient because you used to have to type in the branch twice.

Comment: Before remotes existed, there were several attempts to allow one to not type in a full URL. Those still work, and are why `git fetch` and `git push` have that complicated documentation section describing how you can specify some other Git repository. The invention of the remote, like `origin`, allowed collapsing all of this down into two simple settings, which became the upstream.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [`pull.rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pullrebase), this behavior can also be enabled using [`branch.<name>.rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtrebase) or [`branch.autoSetupRebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchautoSetupRebase). To disable rebasing by default on `git pull`, you need to unset those on all levels of Git configuration (repo, user, system).