# default value of rebase flag in git pull --rebase

Tags: git

From [git pull docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---rebasefalsetruemergespreserveinteractive), we have

> --rebase[=false|true|merges|preserve|interactive]

But what is its default value taken if we just use `git pull --rebase origin master`?

Comment: Note that the long list of alternatives here is relatively new.  Very old Git had only `--rebase=true` or `--rebase=false`.  With binary options like this, the default when it's specified is `true`. Therefore CodeCaster's answer is correct. I'd recommend filing a documentation bug: the docs should have been updated when pull's rebase option grew all these additional values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default is `true`. I can't find any documentation for this, but it is.

The option [`false` is for when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130886/how-to-disable-git-pull-rebase-rebasing-by-default-upon-pull) you have [configured your repo, your branch or your system to always rebase when pulling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846300/how-to-make-git-pull-use-rebase-by-default-for-all-my-repositories).

The other options are explained in the docs.